# maximum setlocal recursion level reached

Tags: batch-file

I am very very newbie to coding though I'm trying to learn and accomplish a automation batch script for my project. So the code below is working flawlessly, but after some time I am getting that

"maximum setlocal recursion level reached"

error and it echos not variable !line! but only "!line!" to my csv file. I have searched a lot of about that and read a lot of issue and tried the solutions, but couldnt manage to fix it. So if anybody can help, I really appreciate it.

My main info.csv file has more than 130 lines. Notice that I'm calling the same bat again after timeout %wait%

```
echo off

(
  for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (info.csv) do @echo(%%~c,%%~a,%%~b)|sort|for /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ('findstr "^"') do @echo(%%~b,%%~a>> ordered.csv

for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (ordered.csv) do echo %%~a%%~b%%~c >>ordered2.csv

(   For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3 Delims=," %%A In ("ordered2.csv") Do (
        if %%C LSS %totalsec% echo %%~A,%%~B,%%~C>> info1.csv

        if %%C GTR %totalsec% echo %%~A,%%~B,%%~C>> notyet1.csv))

@echo off & setlocal

rem // redirect output to new csv file
>"info2.csv" (

    rem // get each line from the old csv file
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("info1.csv") do (
        set "line=%%I"

        rem // get the last column (max 20 columns)
        call set "last=%%line:*,=%%"
        for /L %%# in (1,1,19) do call set "last=%%last:*,=%%"

        rem // remove spaces in last column and reassemble line
        call call set "line=%%%%line:%%last%%=%%last: =%%%%%%"

        rem // output result
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)       

@echo off & setlocal

rem // redirect output to new csv file
>"notyet.csv" (

    rem // get each line from the old csv file
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("notyet1.csv") do (
        set "line=%%I"

        rem // get the last column (max 20 columns)
        call set "last=%%line:*,=%%"
        for /L %%# in (1,1,19) do call set "last=%%last:*,=%%"

        rem // remove spaces in last column and reassemble line
        call call set "line=%%%%line:%%last%%=%%last: =%%%%%%"

        rem // output result
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" info2.csv | find /C ":""
for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set max=%%a
set /a maxx = %max% + 1
echo Total: %max%

echo var i; >> timecheck.js
echo for (i = 1; i ^< %maxx%; i++) { >> timecheck.js
echo iimSet("loop", i); >> timecheck.js
echo iimPlay("timecheck"); >> timecheck.js
echo } >> timecheck.js
endlocal


for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mytime=%time%
SET /A wait=%RANDOM% * 100 / 120768 + 1
if %wait% LSS 5 set /a wait = %wait% + 5
if %wait% GTR 25 set /a wait = %wait% - 5
set /a wait = %wait% * 60
set /a second=%RANDOM% * 100 / 55768 + 1
set /a wait = %wait% + %second%
set /a wait = %wait% / 60

timeout %wait%
1.bat
```

Comment: You should split the problem, up to which part it works and where it fails? Which output files are correct? Do you expect problematic characters in your csv file like `=&"<>%!`?

Comment: Btw. Your first `setlocal` in `@echo off & setlocal` has no matching `endlocal`

Comment: All outputs are good until the error. Error happens in the section where I echo !line!. Does @echo off & setlocal also needs a endlocal?

Comment: The section "rem // redirect output to new csv file" is to extract spaces from the csv files. Before that I'm extracting " characters so there should be no problem.

Comment: Normally you don't need an `endlocal` when the script ends, but in your case you restart the script, therefore the setlocals will stack. You could put an `endlocal` the line before `1.bat`

Comment: Ok, I got it. Will try and inform thank you.

Comment: You have too many unnecessary multi-line code blocks for starters. You have seven opening code block parens  and only four closing parens by my first count.

Comment: At no point do you `echo !line!`, but you do `echo(!line!` which seems strange, given that you don't enable delayed expansion until you're inside the code block where you are going to use it.  Maybe that's some kind of undocumented behavior that works?  Get rid of the `echo(`'s and replace that opening paren with space.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [Ask], might as well read [MCVE] just for good measure. You say "_So the code below is working flawlessly..._" and then you go on say it doesn't?  Which is it?